# I can't import my css into project java web

Tags: css, jsp

How to import file css into project java web?
This is my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Demo Form Angular</title>
<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/formAngular.css"" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p class="contain">Hello Angular</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have double quotes on your `<link` tag.

Comment: By the way, if you're already learning on making a new webapp, why don't you start with the latest technology? use HTML5, not HTML 4.01!

Answer (score 0):

place that link:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/formAngular.css"/>
```

Instead of:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/formAngular.css"" />
```